# Homography matrix multiplication

Tags: opencv, matrix

I am trying to pre multiply a Homography matrix before I send it it the warpperspective function, but I cannot figure out how to do this. I am trying to use gemm for multiplying the matrices. Also How do you specify an element (like HomOffset(0,0)) in a matrix obj then multiply it by a scalar? I have been reading the opencv documentation but did not come across this. Code is below. Thanks in advance.

```
cv:: Mat Hom = cv::findHomography(scene,obj, CV_RANSAC);
cv:: Mat HomOffset[3][3] = {
        { 1, 0, 25 },
            { 0, 1, 25 },
            { 0, 0, 1 }
        };
```

error for declartion of HomOffSet code is int to cv:: Mat is ambigious

```
 gemm(Hom,HomOffset,1,0,0,H);
```

Multiple errors for the gemm function.

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign your Matrix's values (HomOffset) correctly. Use at operator: see it [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.3/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at)